# How to make a picture out of profile pictures?

Tags: image-processing, twitter, information-visualization

I want to create pictures made of profile pictures like the one I attached here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the average RGB value of each profile image.
2. In Photoshop (or just about any other graphics editing software), create a custom palette containing each of these colours
3. Load the photo you want to render, and scale it down so that the width and height in pixels correspond to the number of profile images you want to have in each dimension.
4. Reduce the bit depth of the image to 8 bits or less using the palette you created at step 1. Make sure that the "dithering" option is selected when you do this.
5. Write a script to read in the downsampled image and create a larger image where each pixel of the downsampled image is converted into a single profile image.

Possible enhancements: If there are more than 256 profile images, you're likely to end up with more colours than can be accommodated in a single colour table. Cluster similar colours together in groups and select images at random from these groups when rendering the large image. You could even select images based on how well the distribution of light and shade matches the distribution in the corresponding section of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python project that achieves the photo mosaic effect your looking for: http://john2x.com/projects/photomosaic/

and

on [GitHUB](https://github.com/john2x/photomosaic)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a routine to do that today in C#. I saw a photo mosaic and it suddenly occurred to me how you would do it, so I threw this together as a sort of proof of concept. Worked on my second try. Kinda blew my mind:

```
public void BuildMosaic(string srcFolder, string picFileSrc, string mosaicFile, uint mosaicSizeMultiplier, Size numTiles)
{
    // The file we're going to create a mosaic of
    Image srcPic = Image.FromFile(picFileSrc);
    int mosaicWidth = srcPic.Width * (int)mosaicSizeMultiplier;
    int mosaicHeight = srcPic.Height * (int)mosaicSizeMultiplier;
    int thumbWidth = mosaicWidth / numTiles.Width;
    int thumbHeight = mosaicHeight / numTiles.Height;

    List<ImageInfo> imageInfos = new List<ImageInfo>();
    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(srcFolder))
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToUpper();
        if (ext == ".JPG" || ext == ".PNG" || ext == ".GIF" || ext == ".JPEG")
        {
            imageInfos.Add(ImageInfo.FromImage(filename, new Size(thumbWidth, thumbHeight)));
        }
    }

    int segmentWidth = srcPic.Width / numTiles.Width;
    int segmentHeight = srcPic.Height / numTiles.Height;

    Image mosaic = new Bitmap(mosaicWidth, mosaicHeight);
    Bitmap segBmp = new Bitmap(segmentWidth, segmentHeight);
    for (int tileX = 0; tileX < numTiles.Width; tileX++)
    for(int tileY = 0; tileY < numTiles.Height; tileY++)
    {
        // Create a bitmap from the original image that we'll try to match a tile to.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(segBmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(srcPic, new Rectangle(0, 0, segmentWidth, segmentHeight), new Rectangle(tileX * segmentWidth, tileY * segmentHeight, segmentWidth, segmentHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        ImageInfo segInfo = ImageInfo.FromImage(segBmp);

        // Find the matching tile and paint it onto our mosaic
        ImageInfo match = segInfo.FindMatch(imageInfos.ToArray());
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mosaic))
        {
            g.DrawImage(match.Thumbnail, tileX * thumbWidth, tileY * thumbHeight);
        }
    }
    segBmp.Dispose();
    mosaic.Save(mosaicFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    mosaic.Dispose();
}
```

and the ImageInfo class:

```
public class ImageInfo
{
    private ImageInfo()
    { 
    }

    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public int Blue { get; private set; }
    public int Green { get; private set; }
    public int Red { get; private set; }
    public System.Drawing.Image Thumbnail { get; private set; }

    // Calculate color distance
    private float CalcDistance(ImageInfo otherImage)
    {
        int blueDiff = Math.Abs(Blue - otherImage.Blue);
        int greenDiff = Math.Abs(Green - otherImage.Green);
        int redDiff = Math.Abs(Red - otherImage.Red);
        return (float) Math.Sqrt(blueDiff * blueDiff + greenDiff * greenDiff + redDiff * redDiff);
    }

    // Find the image with the closes matching color average
    internal ImageInfo FindMatch(ImageInfo[] list)
    {
        ImageMatch closest = null;
        foreach (ImageInfo ii in list)
        {
            if (closest == null)
            {
                closest = new ImageMatch()
                {
                    Distance = CalcDistance(ii),
                    Info = ii
                };
                continue;
            }
            float dist = CalcDistance(ii);
            if (dist < closest.Distance)
            {
                closest = new ImageMatch()
                {
                    Distance = CalcDistance(ii),
                    Info = ii
                };
            }
        }
        return closest.Info;
    }

    internal static ImageInfo FromImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap srcBmp)
    {
        ImageStatistics stats = new ImageStatistics(srcBmp);
        return new ImageInfo()
        {
            Blue = (int)stats.Blue.Mean,
            Green = (int)stats.Green.Mean,
            Red = (int)stats.Red.Mean
        };
    }

    internal static ImageInfo FromImage(string filename, System.Drawing.Size thumbSize)
    {
        using(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(filename) as System.Drawing.Bitmap)
        {
            ImageStatistics stats = new ImageStatistics(bmp);
            return new ImageInfo()
            {
                Filename = filename,
                Blue = (int)stats.Blue.Mean,
                Green = (int)stats.Green.Mean,
                Red = (int)stats.Red.Mean,
                Thumbnail = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bmp, thumbSize)
            };
        }
    }

    internal class ImageMatch
    {
        public float Distance { get; set; }
        public ImageInfo Info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

First parameter is the directory with all the "tile" images. They can be any size.
Second parameter is the image that you're going to turn into a mosaic
Third parameter is the output mosaic file.
Fourth is a multiplier. It takes the image in parameter 2 and multiplies the height and width by this value, and that's the size of your mosaic file.
Last parameter is the number of X and y tiles that make up the mosaic.

It uses the AForge image processing library.